# Multiple dataframe transformations based on a single column

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I was looking for a similar question but I did not find a solution for what I want to do. any help is welcome

so here is the code to get an example of my Dataframe :

```
import pandas as pd
L = [[0.1998,'IN TIME,IN TIME','19708,19708','MR SD#5 W/Z SD#6 X/Y',20.5],
     [0.3983,'LATE,IN TIME','11206,18054','MR SD#4 A/B SD#1 C/D',19.97]]

df = pd.DataFrame(L,columns=['Time','status','F_nom','info','Delta'])
```

output :

[image]

I would like to create two new rows for each row in my main dataframe based on **'Info'** column

as we can see on the column **'Info'** in my main dataframe each row contains two different **SD#**
i would like to have only one **SD#** per row

Also i would like to keep the corresponding values of the columns : **Time** , **Status** , **F_norm** ,**Delta**

Finaly create a new column **'type info'** that contains the specific string for each **SD#** (W/Z or A/B etc.) and all this by keeping the index of my main data_frame !

Here is the desired result :

[image]

I hope i was clear enough, waiting for your returns thank you.

Comment: Is the `info` column standardized? Does it always follow the same format or is it dynamic in length?

Comment: @MatíasRomo it's always follow the same format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
#split values by comma or whitespace
df['status'] = df['status'].str.split(',')
df['F_nom'] = df['F_nom'].str.split(',')
info = df.pop('info').str.split()
#select values by indexing
df['info'] = info.str[1::2]
df['type_info'] = info.str[2::2]

#reshape to Series
s = df.set_index(['Time','Delta']).stack()
#create new DataFrame and reshape to expected output
df1 = (pd.DataFrame(s.values.tolist(), index=s.index)
        .stack()
        .unstack(2)
        .reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
        .reset_index())
print (df1)
     Time  Delta   status  F_nom  info type_info
0  0.1998  20.50  IN TIME  19708  SD#5       W/Z
1  0.1998  20.50  IN TIME  19708  SD#6       X/Y
2  0.3983  19.97     LATE  11206  SD#4       A/B
3  0.3983  19.97  IN TIME  18054  SD#1       C/D
```

Another solution:

```
df['status'] = df['status'].str.split(',')
df['F_nom'] = df['F_nom'].str.split(',')
info = df.pop('info').str.split()
df['info'] = info.str[1::2]
df['type_info'] = info.str[2::2]

from itertools import chain

lens = df['status'].str.len()
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Time' : df['Time'].values.repeat(lens), 
    'status' : list(chain.from_iterable(df['status'].tolist())), 
    'F_nom' : list(chain.from_iterable(df['F_nom'].tolist())), 
    'info' : list(chain.from_iterable(df['info'].tolist())), 
    'Delta' : df['Delta'].values.repeat(lens),
    'type_info' : list(chain.from_iterable(df['type_info'].tolist())), 
})
print (df)
     Time   status  F_nom  info  Delta type_info
0  0.1998  IN TIME  19708  SD#5  20.50       W/Z
1  0.1998  IN TIME  19708  SD#6  20.50       X/Y
2  0.3983     LATE  11206  SD#4  19.97       A/B
3  0.3983  IN TIME  18054  SD#1  19.97       C/D
```

Comment: @jezrael was trying to solve this with `pd.melt`, is that possible as well?

Comment: @Erfan - hmm, I think maybe by here is better reshape by stack, unstack, because MultiIndex. But if you really want, is it possible.

Comment: @jezrael that's exactly what I've been trying to do. Tank you